# Como puedo descargar la imagen de openjdk17 para mac M1?

Tags: docker

estoy tratando de descargar la imagen de openjdk17 para docker en un Mac M1 y me arroja el siguiente error al tratar de levantar con docker compose up.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado por varios lados pero no logro encontrar el error. En algunos lados sugieren cambiar la platform por amd64, pero siempre son ejemplos con la imagen de mysql, pero no de openjdk. Algun metodo de poder levantarla??

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que especificar la plataforma para la cual quieres ejecutar la imagen. En este caso `library/openjdk` solo dispone `linux/amd64`. Lo puedes consultar a la [web](https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/17-alpine/images/sha256-a996cdcc040704ec6badaf5fecf1e144c096e00231a29188596c784bcf858d05?context=explore) en `OS/ARCH`.

Añade `--platform linux/amd64` en las comandas `build`,`run`,`pull`. Ya que tu MAC habla tambien esa arquitectura.
O si utilitzas `docker-compose` especifica dentro del objecto servicio: `platform: linux/amd64` ( por debajo de `imagen:` por ejemplo)

*En las properas publicaciones no pastes imagenes, pega el error directamente*